# k-linear category

Tags: category-theory, enriched-category-theory

In the tasks I have it says

"Let $k$ be a field. Show that the structure of a $k$-linear category on a category $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$ being a module category (see [Module category in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+category)) over $\mathrm{vect_k}$, the vector spaces over $k$."

I have a few questions to that:

1) I googled and found that "$k$-linear" means that the category is enriched over $\mathrm{vect_k}$. I found the definition of enriched, but that's really abstract, could somebody maybe explain what enriched over $\mathrm{vect_k}$ explicitly means?

2) What exactly does $k$-linear category ON A CATEGORY $\mathcal{C}$ mean? I never found it like that..

3) For the proof he says as a hint "define $v.c$ for $v \in \mathrm{vect_k}$ and $c \in \mathcal{C}$ as the object representing the functor $v \otimes_k \mathrm{Hom}( - , c)$.
Why do I have to identify an object like $v.c$ as a functor?

Any further hints on how to proof this are of course always good to see, but I am glad if someone can help me understand the question :D

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw: it could be useful if you could provide the references you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I assume you have found [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enriched_category) of enriched category and we are talking of enrichment over a monoidal category.

Personally I believe that the best way to think about enriched categories is to consider them as categories whose $\hom$-functor, the compositions mappings, and the identities *can be lifted* respectively to a $\mathcal V$-valued functor and $\mathcal V$-valued mappings.

I could make this a little more formal but that could be long, so if you need additional details feel free to ask.

A little more concretely, for the case of the monoidal category $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ of $k$-vector spaces (having tensor product $(\otimes)$ as monoidal product, and $k$, the field, i.e. the unique up to isomorphism vector space of dimension 1, as monoidal unit) an enriched category amounts to a category $\mathbf C$ whose $\hom$-sets $\mathbf C[a,b]$ have an additonal (enriching) structure of $k$-linear vector spaces, in which the compositions $\circ_{a,b,c} \colon \mathbf C[b,c] \times \mathbf C[a,b] \to \mathbf C[a,c]$ are $k$-multilinear maps.

2. If you adopt this point of view, and see enriched categories as categories with additional structure (on the $\hom$-sets and on the compositions) then it should be pretty natural to call this additional structure the **$k$-linear category** structure *over* **the (underlying) category** considered (as we talk of the $k$-vector space structure over a set).
3. Since in the formula $v \otimes_k \text{Hom}(-,c)$ you are using the tensor product of $\mathbf{Vect}_k$ I am assuming you are proving that a $k$-linear category is a $\mathbf{Vect}_k$-module category.

Actually the key to understand your hint is in the phrase "*the object **representing** the functor $v \otimes_k \text{Hom}(-,c)$*", this implies that $v.c$ is not a functor but it is an object such that you have a natural isomorphism
$$\text{Hom}(-,v.c) \cong v \otimes_k \text{Hom}(-,c)$$
of $\mathbf{Vect}_k$-valued functors.

I hope this helps, if not feel free to ask for additional details.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I understood 1) and 2) - thanks for that! in 3) I understood what you wrote, its kind of  that there is such a $c' \in \mathcal{C}$ s.t.h $(\mathrm{Hom}(-, c') \cong v \otimes \mathrm{Hom}(-, c)$. and then I can define $v.c$ to be $c'$. Right? I have given that a lot of thought the last hours, but unfortunately I have absolutely no idea, how to find such a $c'$. Do you have any idea there?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It is not clear to me why such a functor should be representable. Is there any additional hypothesis you forgot in the question? Alternatively could you provide the references you have on the subject? (where does the question come from? from which book or article are you getting the definitions?)

Comment: I can start the same way, you did: Unfortunately no. Or at least not all of them. The questions are from a handwritten-collection of exercise I got from my professor. Some of the definitions in there are taken from https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139, "k-linear" and "representable" aren't explained at all, it seams like part of the exercises was to do some research on those terms. The only thing I can add is the next question (as they sometimes correlate) where it says:

Comment: Show: k-linear functor $F: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C'}$ with $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{C'}$ $k$-linear amounts t a $\mathbb{C}$-module functor $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C'}$ ... but I don't think this I really helpful

Comment: A possible way to proceed could be to find a universal element for the $\mathcal V$-functor $v \otimes_k \text{Hom}(-,c)$ but I am not sure what such an element could be.

Comment: @Giorgia Mossa, since I asked this question I have come a little further. I know want to show the other way around, that for a module category I can construct that the $\mathrm{Hom}$-spaces are k-linear. I solved the problem of the scalar multiplication, but I am really confused with the vector addition. Since my basis is a module category I have no addition anywhere near, and the composition is not commutative. Can you help?

Comment: a litte mistake there, the second sentence should be "I now want to show..." sorry

Comment: @P.Schulze Sorry I have read your comment just now, could it be better to talk about this in a private chat?

Comment: no Problem! I think I actually already fixed it - thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the monoidal unit really the $0$ space? Wouldn't it be $K$ if we're talking about vector spaces over $K$?

Comment: IsAdisplayName you're right, I didn't notice at the time. I'll fix in a moment, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

"Let $k$ be a field. Show that the structure of a $k$-linear category on a category $\mathcal{C}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$ being a module category (see [Module category in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+category)) over $\mathrm{vect_k}$, the vector spaces over $k$."

I don't think this is true.  Consider the category where the objects are 7-dimensional vector spaces over the field $k$ and the morphisms are linear maps.  This is a $k$-linear category: that is, it's enriched over $\mathrm{vect_k}$ - or equivalently, in simpler terms, the hom-sets are vector spaces over $k$ and composition is bilinear.   But I don't think it's a module category over $\mathrm{vect_k}$, since you can't tensor a 7-dimensional vector space by an arbitrary vector space and get another 7-dimensional vector space in some way that obeys the axioms of a module category.